# Dynamically adding item to Sitecore - item name must satisfy the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, validation, pattern-matching, sitecore

My pattern is actually:

```
^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$
```

EDIT - for clarity, I do not have this pattern written in my code, but I get an error thrown that says "name does not satisfy pattern ^[\w*\$][\w\s-\$]*((\d{1,})){0,1}$". I think this is a Sitecore setting? I'm not sure where it's determined, and I didn't write it myself.

I'm trying to add articles to Sitecore dynamically, but I'm having an issue with an item that has a period in the name. I added a function to sanitize the names (borrowed from another Sitecore question where it was posted as the answer to my issue), but it's not working. This is my code:

```
var itemTemplateId = _templateFactory.GetTemplateId<IPressReleaseItem>();
TemplateID pressReleaseTemplateId = new TemplateID(itemTemplateId.ToID());
item = folder.Add(SanitizeHeadline(release.Headline), pressReleaseTemplateId);
```

---

```
private string SanitizeHeadline(string name)
{
    char[] invalidCharacters = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.InvalidItemNameChars;
    string sanitizedName = string.Concat(name.Trim().Split(invalidCharacters));
    return sanitizedName;
}
```

My item name is "VirtualInvestorConferences.com Celebrates 75th Event Encouraging Direct Dialog Between CEOs and Shareholders"

Should I just manually add "." to the list of invalid characters? I want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I think it's better to put your current pattern into the question instead of into the title.

Comment: I would use : @"^[\w\.]+\s+\w+\s+(\d+)"  Never use both the ^ for the beginning of the line and $ for the end in the same pattern.  It never works.

Comment: @jdweng: *"Never use both the ^ for the beginning of the line and $ for the end in the same pattern. It never works."*: Sorry, but what a stupid advice!!!

Comment: Prove that I'm wrong!!!  It is unnecessary and more times than not it doesn't work.  There is no reason to have both ^ and $.

Comment: For clarity, I did not write this pattern in my code. It is a Sitecore setting (I think) and an error is getting thrown on `folder.Add(name, templateId)`

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to use `ItemUtil.ProposeValidItemName(name)` to clean up invalid characters from your new item name.